# List AD Users that are part of Group Membership but in specific OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell, organizational-unit

I am trying to list AD users that are a member of a specific group but i need to search one ou at a time

```
Get-ADGroup 'GroupName' | Get-ADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 1):

No worries guys, found a way...

get-adgroupmember "GroupName" | where {$_.distinguishedName -like "*OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=com"} | select Name